# Why is Visual studio not opening the designer file correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a WinForms application made in C# using Visual studio.

Now I want to create a new project including the files which of my previous project. I have included every source file of the previous project, in my new project.
Now this new project is compiling perfectly and working correctly as it is intended to, but when I try to edit my form in designer, it just shows a blank form, instead of the actual form which opens while running the application.

How should I correct that ?

Comment: Try shutting down VS, delete your suo file and re open

Comment: @LawrenceThurman I have tried it but your solution is not working

Comment: Are you hard coding the locations of the controls?  some designer code would help

Comment: You have checked that you added the designer.cs file for the form and its parent?

Comment: @Patrick Yeah! Thanks I hadn't added designer.cs file in the correct position